# Deploying safe infrastructure for a new chain

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk, safe-core

I'm working on adding our chain custom Chain so that we can use safe within our network.
i went and asked for singleton factory address [here](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-singleton-factory/issues/293):

Got this [tx](https://boascan.io/tx/0x2a5726a30ba4ee41d7c031d858a8f63c3ac382dd69bcef8291c332388273d6ce) with the created contract.

Next I cloned this repo and followed the [doc](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-infrastructure/blob/main/docs/running_locally.md) to set it up locally. All good until I am trying to create a safe and it says:

`Error: Invalid CompatibilityFallbackHandler contract address`

I was checking additions like [these](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-deployments/pull/344/files) but they seem to have multiple addresses, I only got one from the initial request.

How can I make it work locally?

Answer (score 0):

After having the singleton factory you need to deploy the safe contracts https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts and add the addresses https://github.com/safe-global/safe-deployments

Comment: Once the steps above are completed, you should wait until a new version of the Safe{Core} SDK is realeased with the `safe-deployments` dependency up to date (given the error I'm assuming you are using it). Otherwise, if you don't want to wait for the new release of the SDK, you can already use it once the contracts are deployed initializing it with the `contractNetworks` option: https://docs.safe.global/safe-core-aa-sdk/protocol-kit/reference#create

Comment: When I am trying to deploy `safe-deployments` using `npm run deploy-all $networkName` I get:

`Safe factory not found for network $NetworkNo. You can request a new deployment at https://github.com/safe-global/safe-singleton-factory.         For more information, see https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts#replay-protection-eip-155`

Comment: NVM I managed to deploy hardcoding `info` variable in `hardhat.config.ts`